# Missing POST route error is not in the error log

Tags: node.js, logging, error-handling

I have a NodeJS server and I forgot to add a route for POST on a page.

I have a GET route, in `routes/public.js`:

```
/**
 * GET /festas
 *
 * 
 */
router.get("/festas", async (req, res) => {
  return res.render('festas', {
    user: req.user,
    text: TEXT,  // equivalent of a global variable
  });
});

router.get("/:token", async (req, res) => {
  // Verifications, such as typos on the requested route,
  // not shown here.
  return res.redirect(301, "/404");
}

module.exports = router;
```

This module is called by `app.js`:

```
app.use('/', require('./routes/public'));
```

and a PUG template:

```
  .feedback
    h2 #{text.feedback.title}

    p #{text.feedback.body}

    .container
      form#commentForm(method="POST")
        .comment
          p #{text.feedback.comments}
  
          input(type="text", name="commentString")
  
        input.primary(type="submit", value="Submit")
```

When I click on the Submit button on the page, I see:

```
Cannot POST /festas
```

But I could not find this error in the error log. I would like to include this error in the error log so I catch this bug quickly in  the future.

How can I add missing POST routes to error logging?

Comment: Can you add more details and code snippets it'll help to understand?

Comment: I added them. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are express server and doing something like this:

```
// router.js
router.get("/festas", async (req, res) => {
  return res.render("festas", {
    user: req.user,
    text: TEXT, // equivalent of a global variable
  });
});

// other routes, GET and POST.

export default router;

// App.js
app.use('/', router);
app.post('*', (req, res) => {
  // All unhandled POST routes end up here.
  console.error("Unhandled POST route: " + req.originalUrl);
  res.send('Not Found', 404);
});
```

Comment: I added code for completeness. It seems your code is equivalent to mine and I don't see how that would log the error on posting to the route.